# Concurrency handling stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

My stored procedure is like this.

Im maintaining a RowVersion in Table A.

1. Starts Transaction
2. Read RowVersion from Table A rw1
3. ...
4. Some Calculations
5. ...
6. Read RowVersion from Table A as rw2
7. Update Some Tables including Table A
8. IF(rw1==rw2)
9. COMMIT
10. ELSE
11. ROLLBACK

Currently im using READ COMMIT as Isolation Level But When its updating Table A RowVersion is also changing.

Goal : when two or more users logged in to system and press a button at same time (which will execute this SP) first one only execute the SP and not allow other one to execute

Comment: Ditch the rowversion comparison and select the rows `with (updlock)`.

Comment: If you want to serialize access to the stored procedure, you could look into using `sp_getapplock`...